# How to bind Navigation Property (second level model's two properties) in DataGridView's single column using BindingSource?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview, bindingsource

I have faced problem to show the values in grid view using binding source. I have two models as `Company` and `Partners`.

1. I have `PartnerId` in Company Model,
2. and Partner model has `FirstName` and `LastName`.

I have showed the company info and partner's first name as shown above.

Now, I need to **show both partner's first name and last name in single column as `PartnerName`**. Could any one help me resolve this?

Comment: Do you have `Partner` navigation property in `Company`?

Comment: yes. I have partner list on company model

Comment: So you can use `CellFormatting` event simply.

Comment: is it possible to achieve this without using any event handlers?

Comment: Yes, by overriding `ToString()` method of `Partner`.

Comment: could you please give some example stuff to do this? since, i am very new to this concept

Comment: You should not put UI related stuff in entity classes. Use `CellFormatting` event as @RezaAghaei suggested. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36549062/hide-certain-properties-of-a-class-in-datagridview/36552399#36552399 and related.

Comment: ok. is there any possible to do at design time? like data property name in combo box column

Comment: @BalagurunathanGM Again yes, but it needs to add a new property to `Partner` class which is not your option and you said in [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36760909/how-to-bind-second-level-models-two-columns-value-as-single-column-in-datagridv/36761711?noredirect=1#comment61101840_36761108)

Comment: @RezaAghaei Ok. Thanks for the solution. Let me do this by using the way that you have suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1 - CellFormatting**

As an option you can use `CellFormatting` event of `DataGridView` and show desired value:

```
void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    //I Suppose you want to show full name in column at index 3
    if(e.RowIndex>=0 && e.ColumnIndex==3)
    {
        var company = (Company)(this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem);
        if (company != null && company.Partner != null)
            e.Value = string.Format("{0} {1}", company.Partner.FirstName,
                                                company.Partner.LastName);
    }
}
```

**Option 2 - ToString()**

As another option you can override `ToString()` method of `Partner` class and show the `Partner` in a column:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("{0} {1}", this.FirstName, this.LastName);
}
```

Comment: Option 1 == +1. Option 2 == no option for me :)

Comment: @IvanStoev Thank you for your feedback. A meaningful `ToString()` override is really useful. I think it's not a UI code. We can use it in `ComboBox`, In `DataGridView` or wherever we need a meaningful string representation of an entity.

Comment: Only if the class is some sort of a ViewModel. Other than that, `ToString` is just for debugging purposes.

Comment: I will go with the option 1. Thanks both you.

Answer (score 0):

Make property which returns formated full name and bind this one to grid cell. You could use multibinding but that needs additional converter which returns (as your additional property) formated string - for example.

Comment: could you please give any example for this?

Comment: In your model class:

private string FirstName;
        private string LastName;
        public string FullName
        {
            get
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(LastName)) return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName);
                else return string.Empty;
            }
        }

And you bind FullName instead of FirstName/LastName